# Add button plus and minus to each td dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have such html structure

```
<td class="cart_quantity">
   <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity'/>
   <input type='text' name='quantity' value='5' class='qty'/>
   <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity'/>
</td>
```

I need add this part in each row in my table. I write jquery for this

```
$('.qtyplus').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
            var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
            } else {
                $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
            }
        });
        $(".qtyminus").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
            var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
            } else {
                $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
            }
        });
```

But problem in that, when i add more row and click on plus or minus, all of them start change. How i can fixed it? I can use twig to add, for example index of loop for each table row for defined it. Something like this

```
 <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus{{loop.index}}' field='quantity'/>
```

Please, help to solve this problem

Comment: Please show the result you want

Comment: how are you adding more rows? Can you post code for that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.prev and $.next to target the input based off the relationship to the button that is being pressed.

```
$('.qtyplus').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $target = $this.prev('input[name=' + $this.attr('field') + ']');
    var currentVal = parseInt($target.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $target.val(currentVal+1);
    } else {
        $target.val(0);
    }
});
$(".qtyminus").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $target = $this.next('input[name=' + $this.attr('field') + ']');
    var currentVal = parseInt($target.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $target.val((currentVal == 0) ? 0 :currentVal-1);
    } else {
        $target.val(0);
    }
});
```

The other option would be `var $target = $this.parent().find('input[name=' + $this.attr('field') + ']')`

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/2youraqu/

This example would cut down the jquery to one function that would target both the plus and minus button using the selector field=quantity then determine of the item has class qtyplus to figure if it's adding or subtracting.

```
$('input[field="quantity"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $target = $this.parent().find('.qty');
    var currentVal = parseInt($target.val());
    //check to see if we're adding one or subtracting one
    var adjustment = ($this.hasClass('qtyplus')) ? 1 : -1;
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        //check to see if adjustment would go negative if so set to 0.
        $target.val((currentVal + adjustment < 0) ? 0 : currentVal + adjustment);
    } else {
        $target.val(0);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/2youraqu/2/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) or [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$('.qtyplus').click(function (e) {
    var $input  = $(this).prev('input');
    ...
});
$('.qtyminus').click(function (e) {
    var $input  = $(this).next('input');
    ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/7yotfe0c/